# How to check how many users are registered with AU til date?

Tags: discussion, users

I would like to check that how many users are registered with AU so far. A graph which shows from start date to til date will be fine. We are going to conduct a Ubuntu workshop for 2 days. I would like to share about the AU support and no of users in AU in the workshop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have tools to show this in our moderator section but as we're not allowed to show you any of the detail in there (of which this probably counts) I built you a query on data.stackexchange.com:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/80302/new-users-per-day

Those are the "new user" counts for each day. If you want a running total, you'll need to build something that accumulates a running total (fairly simple, either in a script or a spreadsheet).

Note: the data on that site isn't live. The latest data on there at the moment is from the end of June. They do dumps every few months.

For other site stats in less depth (but more current) you can look at Stack Exchange:

- http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

### Edit: Got bored; made a graph.

[image]

You can download the spreadsheet from:

- [http://people.ubuntu.com/~oli/au-users-20120626.ods](http://people.ubuntu.com/%7Eoli/au-users-20120626.ods)

Comment: Could you give me the exact count of total registered users till date pls ?? I need the number alone..

Comment: @karthick87 Almost 73k, hover over the user's number here: http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic